# how to hide scroll (overflow:hidden)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have scrollable page with link which opens thickbox.

(see example [landme.ru/scroll-bug/](http://landme.ru/scroll-bug/))

I want to hide vertical scroll when thickbox is opened and stay on the bottom of the page.
Applying 'overflow:hidden' property to 'body' tag does not 
work in ie7. If I use this property for 'html' tag, the page content is 
scrolled up before scroll will be hidden

sorry for my english

UPD: Meanwhile I use such code:

css:
    `.noscroll{overflow:hidden;}`

js:

```
if ( ($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version == '7.0')) {  
   $('html').addClass('noscroll');  
} else {  
   $('body').addClass('noscroll');  
}
```

It works, but I still want to know, if there are any other methods

Comment: I see what you want but this would be really annoying to the user. I think you might ask why would I want to tell the user they can't or can scroll. I sure wouldn't want my scroll bar to disappear.

Comment: I have a lot of content in my thickbox and I need scroll inside thickbox instead scrolling of all page.

Comment: business logic is not the issue here... there's no real reason why we need to know why the poster wants to do this :P

Comment: @Amir Raminfar, [the new york times](http://www.nytimes.com) adds an overlay and removes the scroll to prevent you from reading articles after a certain limit per month. It's funny because they don't stop sending the article's data, so they can still be read for free.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the problem is with the height.  You can't just specify overflow hidden on the wrap because it has no idea where to stop.  Wrap the "wrap" in a div with the style attributes of position:relative; height:100%; then give the wrap the style of overflow: hidden; height: 100%; position: absolute;

lastly you need to scroll it so it's at the bottom.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].scrollTop = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].scrollHeight
```

and there you have it :)

test case here:
http://jsbin.com/eguhuj#html

there is a tiny bit of scroll bar, but that's because of jsbin.  in just an html document it looks perfect.

EDIT: updateed code... can we test this to see if it works first... can you put this in your anchor element?

```
onclick="(function(){var blah = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0];
document.getElementsByClassName("wr")[0].style.position = "absolute";
var meh = document.body.scrollTop;
blah.style.overflow = "hidden";
blah.style.height = "100%";
blah.style.position = "absolute";
blah.scrollTop = meh;})();"
```

Comment: This hide all content on the page (see demo).
Also the page should not shifted simply. 
It not necessarily bottom of page, the link can be in the middle of page for example

Comment: The code above behaves strange.  
It reload page after execution.   
  
Meanwhile I use such code:  
  
css:  
`.noscroll{overflow:hidden;}`  
  
js:  
`if ( ($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version == '7.0')) {  
        $('html').addClass('noscroll');  
      } else {  
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');  
      }`  
  
It works, but I still want to know, if there are any other methods